# Is there a downside to using heavy armor as a mage?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there disadvantages to wearing armor as a mage casting spells?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34958/are-there-disadvantages-to-wearing-armor-as-a-mage-casting-spells)

I am playing a mage in skyrim (100% magicka increase per level). So basically my health is pretty low.

Now cloth items do not seem to have high armor ratings. I thought I could use heavy armor instead.

I thought of using the Astronach Forge to create deadric armor, so I do not have to invest any perks in smithing.

Furthermore I am currently at 100 enchanting, thus I can use very good enchants on any item, like heavy armor.

Say I invest some time and perks in heavy armor and remove the speed penalty, then heavy armor should be the best way to go.

Do I miss something?

Comment: as it says in the above dup link, No your not missing any thing.

in fact i think that sounds like a great plan.

Comment: This is pretty funny that a duplicate has over 10k views lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heavy armor doesn't hurt your spell-casting in any way, so feel free to load up. Since you say you are only spending levelup stat boosts on magicka, that means your stamina will be low, which means a lower carry weight. Heavy armor will, obviously, be rather heavy. That's the only real downside I can think of. Since you have maxed enchanting, losing the mage-centric buffs on robes isn't too big of a deal, since you can replicate them on your armor.

Further on that point, you really really shouldn't ignore stamina or, more importantly, health. You will die a million times later in the game when a stray arrow from a bandit can one-shot you with such painfully low health.